# Symfony 2 own Field Type - always "This value is not valid" error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I've created a new Form Field Type called "gamesetting". This Type should handle text inputs and checkboxes, based on the value of the data array. The form is built correctly but when I submit the form I always get the error "This value is not valid" if the value of the input is not empty. If the checkbox is unchecked or the text field is empty, the form is valid.

The Form is using only a key-value array as data input and not a Model/Entity Object.

```
<?php

namespace asdf\WebinterfaceBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class GamesettingType extends AbstractType {
    function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setRequired([ 'field_type' ]);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'label' => false,
            'field_type' => 'text',
            'required' => false
        ]);
    }

    function getName() {
        return 'gamesetting';
    }

    function getParent() {
        return 'form';
    }

    function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        $view->vars['field_type'] = $options['field_type'];
    }
}
```

The action method looks like:

```
public function settingsAction(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $game = GameFactory::factory(PortlistFactory::byUserAndActive($user->getUsername()));

    // Generate the settings form. Each setting has a internal identifier,
    // a type (which form element) and a label. The label is equal to the
    // identifier and will be translated with the corresponding i18n key.
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder();
    foreach ($game->getSettings()->read('config') as $key => $value) {
        $sanitized_key = str_replace('.', '_', $key);
        $sanitized_value = in_array($value, ['true', 'false']) ? !!($value == 'true') : $value;
        $type = (in_array($value, ['true', 'false'])) ? 'checkbox' : 'text';

        if ($type == "text") {
            $form->add($sanitized_key, 'gamesetting', [
                'field_type' => 'text',
                'data' => $sanitized_value,
            ]);
        } elseif ($type == "checkbox") {
            $form->add($sanitized_key, 'gamesetting', [
                'field_type' => 'checkbox',
                'data' => $sanitized_value,
            ]);
        }

    }
    $form = $form->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        var_dump($form->getData());

        exit;
    }

    return [
        'game' => $game,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create Symfony form elements they have various properties with default values. One of these is 'required' which defaults to true.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/text.html#required

If the browser you are using supports HTML5 form validation, it will display an error if you attempt to submit an empty value for any Symfony form element with required=true. For this reason, I *always* set required=false when constructing form fields. This put you in control of your form validation.